# Issue while ionic installation

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, npm

I am using the following command for installing cordova and ionic :

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

After running the command, i am getting the following error :

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601

npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\node

js\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "npm" "-g"

npm ERR! node v0.12.7

npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3

npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package generator-karma does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!

npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-angular@0.12.1 wants generator-karma@>=0.9.0

npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-angular-ui-router@0.5.3 wants generator-karma@~0.5.0

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

npm ERR!     D:\iconic_start\npm-debug.log
```

I am having npm and node installed.

Answer (score 2):

Probably some packages are outdated.

Try to run:

```
npm update -g
```

That will update everything, install missing packages, etc. Or as per the docs:

> npm update -g will apply the update action to each globally- installed
>   package that is outdated -- that is, has a version that is different
>   from latest.

That should fix your problem.

More info on the update command [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update).

---

If not, simply try to reinstall your node.js.

Comment: Updated my npm to **v2.11.3** and my node to **v0.12.7**                                                Getting the same above error, along with the following additional error :                                                           npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, but bundled packag
e wasn't found in unpacked tree
C:\Users\rkangale\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic -> C:\Users\rkangale\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
modules\ionic\bin\ionic

Comment: Did you try to make a clean install of node.js after that?